# My Quick Launch disappeared in Windows 8. How to restore it with its icons?

Tags: windows-8

My Quick Launch disappeared after a restart in Windows 8. I restarted my computer many times before and Quick Launch didn't disappear but it happened this last time.

There's a [hot fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/979155) for this issue in Windows 7 but I am running Windows 8.

I can see the Quick Launch folder under C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch.

How do I manually fix this issue? I am guessing a shortcut to the Quick Launch folder needs to be added somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I created a new Quick Launch toolbar and everything came back.